# Is there a $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

For a arbitrary positive $\varepsilon$, is there a $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\underset{(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in X}{\sup}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq n_\varepsilon}|a_n|\right)\leq \varepsilon\text{ },$$
where $X$ is bounded in $\ell_1$?

PS: $\ell_1$ is a sequence space such that:

$$\ell_n=\left\{(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty};a_i\in\mathbb{K}, \forall i\in\mathbb{N} \text{ and }\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|^n<\infty\right\},$$

where $\mathbb{K}$ is the scalar space. Also, the norm $||\cdot||_n$ is given by

$$||(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}||_n=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

My attempt is:

For all $a\in X$, there is a $M>0$ such that $||a||_1\leq M$. Than take a sequence $(a_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ in $X$ and we have
$$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty|a_j|\right)=||(a_j)_{j=1}^\infty||_1\leq M.$$

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit less formally, another way to think about the given condition is that it's asking whether the elements (that is, the sequences) of the bounded set $X$ form series with uniformly small tails. For any finite $X$, this is certainly true, and you might try proving it for sets like that first. The proof might suggest to you what could go wrong when $X$ is infinite.

A slightly easier problem where the same ideas are in play is to address whether, given a bounded $X\subset \ell^1$, there is an $n_0$ such that
$$
\sup_{\{a_n\}\in X}\sum_{n\ge n_0}|a_n| = 0\ ?
$$
This questions asks you if the elements of $X$ form series whose tails are all dead zero if you "wait" long enough. I think it is clearer what the answer is to this question, and it also suggests a possible approach to the problem you are considering.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $X=\{e_j\mid j\in \mathbf N\}$, where $(e_j)_n=\delta_{j,n}$. This is trivially bounded by $1$ and does not have the property you ask about.